# Nonparametric Bootstrap for Bivariate

Tags: r

I'm having trouble getting my nonparametric bootstrap working, since I'm clearly doing something off.

Say I have a vector with two columns (length of n) and I wish to find their correlation.
Let's call this variable data, so length(data[,1])   is equal to n.

Suppose I want N samples.
I start with

```
r=rep(NA,N)
```

r is referring to the bootstrap sample, as I'm trying to estimate correlation coefficient
then I construct a for loop:

```
for(i in 1:N){
column1=sample(data[,1], n, replace=T)
column2=sample(data[,2], n, replace=T)
sample.data=data.frame(column1,column2)
r[i]=corr(sample.data)
}
```

The thinking is, I want to resample each column individually, then take the correlation at the end, but I think theoretically that is incorrect. something is wrong because later results will not work.

If anyone could please lend any help I would appreciate.

Comment: You need to resample the pairs together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that you're resampling as if the pairs were independent, when your assumption is clearly that they're not (since you're trying to estimate their correlation).

For a bootstrap, you need to resample the pairs together.

[If instead you were doing a permutation test for independence against an alternative that they're correlated, you'd treat them as independent under the null.]

Comment: Yes this was the issue. Like you said, they're not independent, so it wouldn't make sense to sample them as such. I modified that and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @sahimat No problem. I'm not sure why this was migrated to SO; while the question had code in it, it's really a statistics issue not a programming issue.